# App crash when returning from Camera or Gallery without picking an image

Tags: android, android-studio

My App crash when returning from the Camera or Gallery without picking an image. But if you pick an image or take a picture the app doesn't crash.

The camera is working fine but if you try to return to the screen without taking a picture the app will crash. same as the gallery function.

if anyone has a suggestion about fixing this issue feel free to respond

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode== CAMERA_PERM_CODE){
        if (grantResults.length < 0 && grantResults [0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            // openCamera() ;
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Camera Permission is Required to use Camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
private void askCameraPermissions() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, CAMERA_PERM_CODE);

    }else {
        opencamera();

    }
}
private void opencamera() {
    Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(camera,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        SelectedImage.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
    else if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        Uri Imageuri = data.getData();
        SelectedImage.setImageURI(Imageuri);
    }
}

private File saveBitMap(Context context, View drawView){
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File pictureFileDir = new File(sdCard.getAbsoluteFile()+"/test");
    pictureFileDir.mkdir();

    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() +File.separator+ System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
    File pictureFile = new File(filename);
    Bitmap bitmap =getBitmapFromView(drawView);
    try {
        pictureFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream oStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, oStream);
        try {
            oStream.flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        oStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("TAG", "There was an issue saving the image.");
    }
    scanGallery( context,pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
    return pictureFile;
}

//create bitmap from view and returns it
private Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    //Define a bitmap with the same size as the view
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    //Bind a canvas to it
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    //Get the view's background
    Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null) {
        //has background drawable, then draw it on the canvas
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }   else{
        //does not have background drawable, then draw white background on the canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    // draw the view on the canvas
    view.draw(canvas);
    //return the bitmap
    return returnedBitmap;
}


// used for scanning gallery
private void scanGallery(Context cntx, String path) {
    try {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(cntx, new String[]{path}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("TAG", "There was an issue scanning gallery.");
    }


}
```

}

Comment: You are not checking the `resultCode` in `onActivityResult()` to see if it is `RESULT_OK` or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check that in `onActivityResult()` result is received or not so check it with `RESULT_OK`. When you returning back without pick image then your data is null

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        SelectedImage.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
    else if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode = RESULT_OK) {
        Uri Imageuri = data.getData();
        SelectedImage.setImageURI(Imageuri);
    }
}
```